# How do I create an input text in visualforce page so that it formats the phone number to standard (555) 555-5555?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have very little experience in apex classes/visualforce pages, so hopefully I can get some help updating an existing code in our org.

Current code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
     Home Phone: <apex:inputtext value="{!PGPhone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

PGPhone is String data type in the controller so when I tried the input type="number", it errored out incompatible data type.

Comment: You seem to be missing your code, can you edit your post to update it with what you have now?

Comment: The body of my post has the code on it, but it seems anything with <> tags were redacted

Comment: Use code formatter to be able to post it.

Comment: @Hazel, you just needed a blank line before your code block. I fixed it.

Comment: So are you looking this to be saved as standard format on a phone field in backend? Or you are looking this to be displayed on your UI as standard phone format?

Comment: @Jayant, I want this displayed in the UI as standard format. I tried the apex:inputField then bind it to the HomePhone field, but then I realized I do need to do this in several contacts on the visualforce page, so I saw the need to create individual variables for them:  PGPhone (for primary guardian), SGPhone (for the secondary guardian), etc.

Comment: I think you can not simply do that...and you need jQuery ...https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095o2IAA

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ayub. I saw that was a solution of masking the display input. I am not really looking to mask it. Just when a user enters a phone number 5554448888, on tab or when moving to the next field, it displays the phone number in this format - (555) 444-8888 and save it like that.   I hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When possible, try using apex:inputField instead:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!contactRecord.Phone}" />
```

This should automatically invoke the default phone-formatting behavior of the UI.

Note that "number" does not mean "phone number", it means "a numeric value" (digits only).

Otherwise, you might write some logic on your field in JavaScript:

```
 <apex:inputText value="{!PGPhone}" onblur="formatPhone(this)" />
```

You can find many examples of formatting a phone number using JavaScript on the Internet; it depends on how particular you want to be, which may be anything from [i18n formatting](https://github.com/leodido/i18n.phonenumbers.js/blob/master/README.md) to simple US-only formats.

Comment: Hi @sfdfox, I did try that and it worked, but then we are using this one visualforce page to accept several contacts (Primary Guardian, Secondary Guardian, etc) and they all use the same Home Phone standard fields. So maybe this is the reason why the they were created variables in the controller for each phone number.

Comment: To do that, you can create several Contact record variables, or even a list of Contact records you could iterate over. You might want to think more about your design. Leveraging apex:inputField to gain default behavior is preferable.

Comment: Can you give an example how to do that? Each phone already have variables (ex. PGPhone, SGPhone, etc). They were declared Public String in the controller and inserted as PG_ct.HomePhone = PGPhone.  I tried the apex:inputField value="{!PGPhone}" but an error says inputField value cannot bind into non SObjects.

Comment: @Hazel Correct, you'd need to declare contact variables, like `public Contact pg { get; set; }`, which you'd reference in your Visualforce as `apex:inputField value={!pg.phone}"`